# Is there an R package to produce forest plots for subgroup analysis in clinical trials

Tags: r, statistics, r-forestplot

I am looking for an R package to produce a forest plot for a subgroup analysis in a clinical trial. A typical example is provided below

[image]

It is a little bit different from a forest plot for a meta-analysis for which there are many dedicated packages. I am looking for an elegant way to do both computation of Hazard Ratios and graphical display.

Comment: "SO" is not really intended to help users find packages, in fact that is deemed [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ... though I confess I've not found a Stack (or other) site that is both appropriate and sufficiently visited to have reasonable suggestions. I see questions here on SO "get away with it" by reformulating the question to be how to reproduce this plot given data (that you need to provide us), and even better if you can attempt code to start the process. Often, if a package exists, somebody recommends it even if you don't ask that question.

Comment: By doing that, there are a few benefits: (1) fewer (if any) votes to close for being off-topic (there is one here already); (2) if there is a package, you may hear about it; (3) if there is not a package, you may come around to a solution that sufficiently addresses your needs, so perhaps no package required. Just my opinion, good luck!